# Tomcat 8 converts hyphens to %2D in the URL

Tags: java, tomcat

How to prevent Tomcat from encoding hyphens (-) to %2D in URLs. This behaviour causes some session related issues when requests are made from Safari browser.

Deployed war file: `my-app.war`

Generated url: `/my%2Dapp`

Desired url: `/my-app`

Comment: What is the value of `URIEncoding` attribute in `Connector` tag of `conf/server.xml` ?

Comment: <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />

Comment: We are running Tomcat 8 and webapps with hyphens in them. We don't have any problems at all. Maybe there is some other problem?

Comment: please add the code which generates `/my%2Dapp`

Comment: `/my%2Dapp` is generated by Tomcat after my-app.war is deployed. I believe there is something to do with Tomcat's config as Tomcat Host Manager Application application (which comes with Tomcat by default) contains the same replaces characters `/host%2Dmanager/`.

Comment: Could you check the encoding of your Tomcat files? Could they be ISO-8859?

Comment: The encoding is set to `ISO-8859` only in `tomcat/conf/web.xml`. Other config files use `UTF-8` encoding. Changed that encoding to `UTF-8`, but unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: @vim What is the problem you have? This is a fully valid URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are referring to the links generated by the Tomcat Manger:
The issue you experience is rooted not in any `Context` configuration but in the [`HTMLManagerServlet`](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/manager/HTMLManagerServlet.java). This servlet includes the following [line](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/manager/HTMLManagerServlet.java#L448#L449):

```
 "<a href=\"" + URL_ENCODER.encode(contextPath + "/")
```

which is a custom encoder: [`org.apache.catalina.util.URLEncoder`](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/util/URLEncoder.java). The static instance employed in the code does not use the [`DEFAULT`](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/util/URLEncoder.java#L41-L49) singleton which marks following chars as safe:

```
public static final URLEncoder DEFAULT = new URLEncoder();
static {
    DEFAULT.addSafeCharacter('~');
    DEFAULT.addSafeCharacter('-');
    DEFAULT.addSafeCharacter('_');
    DEFAULT.addSafeCharacter('.');
    DEFAULT.addSafeCharacter('*');
    DEFAULT.addSafeCharacter('/');
}
```

but rather does [this](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/manager/HTMLManagerServlet.java#L89-L93):

```
static {
    URL_ENCODER = new URLEncoder();
    // '/' should not be encoded in context paths
    URL_ENCODER.addSafeCharacter('/');
}
```

So the outcome is that every single char except `/` is URL-encoded with UTF-8.

Comment: Yes, you a right @Michael-O. The issue exists in HTMLManagerServlet. I have deployed application using `cargo-maven2-plugin` and now all urls look fine. So is there a bug in HTMLManagerServlet behaviour or it can be reconfigured somewhere?

Comment: @vim You can't. This is hardcoded in the servlet. You this causes a problem, I'd recommend to file an issue with Apache Tomcat. Is this worth the bounty?

Answer (score 1):

I think you shouldn't try to control this manually. Instead, you need to define your own context file under conf/Catalina/localhost/my-app.xml
Then :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Context docBase="/some/path/to/my-app.war">
</Context>
```

You can play around with this until you get the correct behavior that you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the path in the context configuration:

```
<Context path="/myAppPath" docBase="h:/foo/mywar.war" reloadable="true" />
```

In this case you can use:  `http://domain/myAppPath/`